# Partial rebase of project

Tags: git, rebase

I work on a huge project and actually only need certain directories of it. So my project looks like:

```
project
 |- a/
 |- b/
 \- foo
```

However, upstream the project looks like:

```
project
 |- a/
 |- b/
 |- c/
 |- foo
 \- bar
```

So I have in my .gitignore:

```
c/
bar
```

However, I am now trying to rebase upstream onto master and I want to be able to tell git that patches/hunks applying to bar, c/* or any things in .gitignore should be automatically skipped. However, it should be careful that single patches that change hunks in foo and bar have it only applied in foo and ignored in bar (don't just ignore the whole patch).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If I understand this correctly you don't want the ignored files in the new upstream branch _upstream'_.  So why not do a normal git rebase and then delete all remaining unwanted files from _upstream'_ using a new commit?

Answer (score 1):

Git operates on "commit objects", not files / directories.  Each commit object has an unique commit ID which is a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of its previous commit id and the changes of that commit.

Which means that ignoring some files / directories would create a different commit ID - so it's basically equivalent to rebasing all the upstream changes, then creating a new commit which deletes all the files that you don't like.

You could probably do that locally with some scripts, but if you do that, every single commit in your local repository will be different from the version on the server, so you'd have to merge each time you pull new upstream changes / push something upstream.

Maybe you could convince the maintainers of the upstream project to split it into smaller submodules ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I guess you have to filter that yourself. There is no git command for this.

Try your luck by exporting with `git format-patch`, do a `difffilter` and `git am` them again.